# Disable full screen when publish in .exe flash

Tags: flash, exe, actionscript-2

So I have a little problem, there's this animation that I'm working with in flash cs 5.5 and now I'm done. So, I have to publish it as .exe, but I want the full screen disabled. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can force the normal display state of your `Stage` when the `fullScreen` event is fired like this :

```
var event_listener:Object = {}
event_listener.onFullScreen = function(fullscreen:Boolean)
{   
    // if it's the fullscreen mode, then set it to normal mode
    if(fullscreen){
        Stage.displayState = 'normal';
    }
}
Stage.addListener(event_listener);
```

But if your problem is only to avoid resizing and scaling your animation by the user, you can simply do :

```
Stage.scaleMode = 'noScale';
```

Hope that can help.